# Topological space modeled by special topological structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds, schemes

Let $X$ be a topological space.  Suppose it is "modeled by" **topological spaces of the form $\text{Spec}(A)$** for some commutative ring $A$, then, (along with some other conditions/structure), we call $X$ a scheme.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose it is "modeled by" **topological spaces of the form $\mathbb{R}^n$**, then, (along with some other conditions/structure), we call $X$ a topological/smooth manifold.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose it is "modeled by" **topological spaces of the form $(Y,d)$; that is a metric space**, then, (along with some other conditions/structure), do we have a name for this kind of spaces?

More generally, do we have names/are they studied extensively, for topological spaces "modeled by", say

1. topological spaces of the form $(Y,\|\cdot\|)$; that is normed spaces
2. topological spaces of the form $(Y, \langle\cdot\rangle)$; that is inner product spaces.
3. ...
4. ...

Comment: If you add completeness to 1. and 2., you should get Banach manifolds and Hilbert manifolds, respectively. Your third paragraph describes locally metrizable spaces, I think.

Comment: I am Happy with Banach and Hilbert manifold comment... I have nothing to say about locally metrizable space... I think something beyet can be said...

Comment: I agree with Robert Furber - it seems that the most natural notion here is "modeled by X-type" = "locally X-type" (and for yet another example, "modeled by linear orderings" gives "[locally ordered spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11194)"). Is there a reason this is unsatisfying?

Comment: @NoahSchweber can you add about locally ordered spaces as an answer and say what has been already studied about that?